# Transform xslt not transforming all elements

Tags: xslt

I am importing an xml file into Access, and using an xslt file to transform the file to include the orderNumber for each section. Not sure of the proper term.
In the code below I am getting the field and orderNumber added for the items, and only the field for the other sections, shippingAddress, payment, etc..

I do not quite understand were I need to make changes to get the data for orderNumber added to the fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greg

This is what I am given to work with.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<orders xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
-<order>
        <orderNumber>100000379</orderNumber>
-<billingAddress>
            <company>Acme</company>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <address1>59 Any St</address1>
            <address2/>
            <city>New York</city>
            <state>NY</state>
            <zip>10013-4020</zip>
            <country>US</country>
            <phone>212-555-1212</phone>
        </billingAddress>
-<shippingAddress>
            <company>Acme</company>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <address1>59 Any St</address1>
            <address2/>
            <city>New York</city>
            <state>NY</state>
            <zip>10013-4020</zip>
            <country>US</country>
            <phone>212-555-1212</phone>
        </shippingAddress>
        <createdOn>2016-06-22 14:38:06</createdOn>
        <shipMethod>ups_GND</shipMethod>
        <shipDescription>United Parcel Service - Ground</shipDescription>
-<payment>
            <tax>0</tax>
            <shipmentCost>26.76</shipmentCost>
            <subtotalExclTax>1616</subtotalExclTax>
            <subtotalInclTax>1616</subtotalInclTax>
            <discount>0</discount>
            <grandTotal>1642.76</grandTotal>
            <paymentMethod>purchaseorder</paymentMethod>
        </payment>
-<items>
-<item>
                <itemId>645</itemId>
                <productId>171</productId>
                <sku>12749</sku>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <price>858</price>
                <tax>0</tax>
                <itemTotal>858</itemTotal>
            </item>
-<item>
                <itemId>646</itemId>
                <productId>178</productId>
                <sku>127478</sku>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <price>758</price>
                <tax>0</tax>
                <itemTotal>758</itemTotal>
            </item>
        </items>
    </order>
</orders>
```

This is the xslt code. I found this as an example, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="billingAddress">
    <billingAddress>
        <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../orderNumber"/></orderNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </billingAddress>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shippingAddress">
    <shippingAddress>
        <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../orderNumber"/></orderNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </shippingAddress>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="payment">
    <payment>
        <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../orderNumber"/></orderNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </payment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
    <item>
        <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../orderNumber"/></orderNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Parfait, Thank you very much. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<orderNumber>` element is a sibling of `<billingAddress>`, `<shippingAddress>`, `<payment>` but a level above `<items>`. So your context level directive `../../` only works for `<item>` node.

Simply replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../orderNumber"/>
```

with a common expression as `<order>` is the ancestor to all the required nodes:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::order/orderNumber"/>
```